# Script to iterate on all utf8-based files and rename them based on content found

Tags: command-line, powershell, script, shell-script, rename

*You may skip the following which is a preface that provides some context to what I am trying to do:*

I have a lot of files which are data points of a Nasa satellite (MERRA-2) of different cities. When I batch download them using wget, they all come with a fixed name, and change the extension to `.1` `.2` `.3` [...]. If I try to force rename it inside the wget command line (let's say, to the name of the city it corresponds to), it somehow corrupts the file/data structure (it is a `.csv`)

Because of that, I'm just downloading the default way and batch renaming it afterward using Bulk Rename Utility (changing the `.1` `.2` `.3` for `.csv` and having a prefix going from 1 to x)

Now I have to rename each file to its correspondent city and year. I've written a simple JavaScript to generate the ren command prompt to do so when I generate the wget download links, and it was working fine in the tests.

My problem is that each file, from the total of 2961, has 1.6Mb and takes like 55 minutes to download (downloads at 500 bytes per second), so I have to let it download overnight. The next day I've come to see that the download was done, but only 100ish of all 141 cities have been downloaded. That is happening day after day, and the problem seems to be on the Nasa server. Other partners in this project say they're also seeing those speeds... from 500bytes to 2kbps...

Having it fail the download of random cities renders my ren script useless.

Now I have a bunch of `.csv` files that have the same name (only differing by a prefix from 1 to 100), that I need to rename with its city name. The only way of knowing which city a given file corresponds to is to open it and look for the latitude data, and referring to another table I have here.

---

I need to build a command-line script that iterates on all the `.txt` files inside a folder, finds, let's say, the latitude `-3.58035`, and renames that file for `CITYNAME`, changing its format from `.txt` to `.csv`, or at least maintaining it as `.txt`.

With this script in hand, I can write some JS to generate more scripts to change the names of all the files based on each of the 141 different latitudes I have.

Here is a sample of the file content:

> time,latitude[unit="degrees_north"],longitude[unit="degrees_east"],BCSMASS[unit="kg m-3"],DUSMASS[unit="kg m-3"],DUSMASS25[unit="kg m-3"],OCSMASS[unit="kg m-3"],SO4SMASS[unit="kg m-3"],SSSMASS[unit="kg m-3"],SSSMASS25[unit="kg m-3"] 2000-01-01T00:30:00Z,-3.58035,-59.1315,2.800106813083403E-10,3.508830559439957E-9,9.654286259319633E-10,3.5261109587736428E-9,2.061603110448118E-10,3.2207483902091383E-10,8.28777324546337E-11

In this case, `-3.58035` is the latitude.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: You could probably script this pretty easily with [Python](https://www.python.org/). It has good text file support and even has a built-in CSV module. It would fairly trivial to 1) get a directory listing then 2) open each CSV file and 3) extract your data. You could then compare the data and your city names via, say, a dictionary in the script and rename the file (including any date data) based on that.

Comment: @Anaksunaman thank you for the guide! Will do.

Comment: @DavidPostill no need to be acid with "superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service". I was just not familiar at all with scripts on command-line. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing it myself* using JS/NodeJS:

```
const fs = require('fs')

//the Dict was much bigger, I've cut it down for this answer
//also, I had to include the "," before and after the key, because one of
//the cities had lat -2.86 and another -2.8611, and that was kinda breaking it.

var latsDict = {
    ",-3.58035,":"AUTAZES",
    ",-3.81212,":"CAREIRO",
    ",-3.19815,":"CAREIRO DA VÁRZEA",
    ",-3.20113,":"IRANDUBA",
    ",-3.14198,":"ITACOATIARA"
}
var latsLen = Object.keys(latsDict).length
var year = 2010
var directory = `/Users/Misharin/Desktop/Nasa/${year}/`

fs.readdir(directory, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return
    }
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        fs.readFile(`${directory}${file}`, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return
            }
            for (var i = 0; i <= latsLen; i++){
                var currentLatKey = Object.keys(latsDict)[i]
                var currentLatValue = Object.values(latsDict)[i]
                if(data.includes(currentLatKey)){
                    console.log(`${file}\t${currentLatValue}`)
                    fs.rename(`${directory}${file}`, `${directory}${currentLatValue.replace(/\s+/g,'-').replace(/[ÀÁÂÃÄ]/g,"A").replace(/[ÈÉÊË]/g,"E").replace(/[ÍÌÎÏ]/g,"I").replace(/[ÓÒÔÖÕ]/g,"O").replace(/[ÚÙÛÜ]/g,"U").replace(/[Ç]/g,"C")}-${year}.csv`, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                            return
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
})
```

The code uses NodeJS:

1. list the files inside the directory;
2. read the file as utf8 (no need to convert to .txt, I was able to use it as .1 .2 .3 and so on) and see if it includes the Key (latitude) from the object;
3. rename it for the Key's value, if it does include that Key, also changing the extension to .csv

I'm aware it is not the best way of tackling it. It may be heavy-duty if there are too many files/bigger dictionary. But for my need, it was enough.